# Make django modelchoicefield readonly true

Tags: jquery, django

On my edit page,I am trying to allow user to edit/change what they have entered, with one condition that they cant edit Modelchoice field.

So, I tried this command but it didn't work. With **"readonly= True"** user still can change the modelchoicefield "dropdown file" while with **"disabled = True"** user can't change the modelchoicefield but when they try to submit they get this error: ***"This field is required."***

myform.py

```
class NameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model=Name
         fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(NameForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.fields['names'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'True'
         #self.fields['names'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
```

Anyone with solution..?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Setting `disabled` or `readonly` only changes the way that the widget is rendered in the html. It doesn't prevent users from submitting a different value. If you don't want a field to be edited, you should remove the field from the form by setting `fields` or `exclude`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @Alasdair, but i want users to be able to see the field but being unable to edit/change it.

Comment: If you are using the Django admin you can use [`readonly_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields). If you are using your own views and templates, you can simply include `{{ instance.field }}` in the template to show the value.

Comment: If you must show a form field, then you'll have to do something in the form/view to prevent the value from being saved. You could look at how the user change form [prevents the password from being changed](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L140) for inspiration. If you disable the widget, you'll have to set `required=False` to prevent the error you were getting before.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar scenario also in our project and fixed it. So, you could try solving your issue this way:

```
class NameForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
         model = Name
         fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(NameForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)       
         instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)

         # When in EDIT mode.
         if instance and instance.id:
             self.fields['names'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = 'True'
             self.fields['names'].required = 'False'

    def clean_names(self):
        instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)

        # `disabled` field will have no form data,
        # so we just use the previously saved value.
        if instance and instance.pk:
            return instance.names
        else:
            # When in CREATE mode.
            return self.cleaned_data['names']
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. In this example, clean_event should be clean_names, so Django would pick the right clean function.

Comment: You're right, forgot to align the method name with OP's specific case. Updated it now. Thanks